# Integrate pdf excel word viewer on a website

Tags: web-apps, library, javascript

I would like to integrate a viewer tool for viewing files in PDF, MS Excel, and MS Word formats. I am developing a website that store manuals on our server and I would like visitors to be able to view these manuals online instead of downloading. I found a tool named ViewerJS that can view PDF and Open Documents online. However the tool doesn't support Microsoft Office.

- Must support displaying at least:

  - .pdf
  - .docx
  - .xlsx
- Prefer Open Source and Gratis
- Licensed software with price up to $2000USD would possibly work.

Comment: Looking good, got a couple questions; Do you care whether it is Open Source? What price range is acceptable?

Comment: We prefer Open Source solution. However, we can also consider Licence solution perhaps from few hundreds to couple of thousands USD.

Thank much for your edition.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Steve Barnes suggestion, JODReports sits on top of Open Office and Libre Office so can take a fair bit of the leg work out of driving Open Office / Libre Office via the API.  The conversions are often surprisingly good, but you'd have to run some tests to determine if that works for your documents well enough.

Comment: Thank @jowierun for your information. I will try later because I am doing another project. The question was asked a long time ago. Anyway, that is very interesting to learn about the tool.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use LibraOffice in command line convert mode to generate an appropriate view of a lot of such documents.  See [this](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/) for some information.

That would allow your server to provide a view of the documents supported by LibraOffice (which is free) but I would recommend providing a download link as well.  Your choice would be whether to convert on view - *slower viewing*, convert on upload - slower uploads and more storage new documents only, convert on first view and keep converted or batch convert everything.

Comment: Thank @SteveBarnes for your information. Maybe we will first use convert on view. If we have more traffic we can use the second option. I never tried LibraOffice for converting, I am not sure if layout of these documents still can be kept. We have around 100GB of manuals.

Comment: Generally it works quite well but you do need to play with the flags sometimes - don't forget the --headless option it is important in this sort of case.